# T-SQL - Filtro de exclusão "NOT IN" não funciona

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, tsql

Eu estou filtrando a minha base por código de loja (varchar), mas o filtro não está removendo os códigos de loja que eu quero excluir da minha consulta. Minha consulta é essa:

```
SELECT A.CPF
     , A.[Cod Loja]
     , B.NomeLoja
     , A.Data_Cadastro
INTO Cadastro
FROM Tabela_Geral A
LEFT JOIN Tabela_Lojas B
ON A.[Cod Loja] = (B.[Cod Loja]*1)  
AND B.NomeLoja <> ''
WHERE A.Data_Cadastro <= @FIM_MES
AND A.[COD LOJA] NOT IN ('5100', '5106', '5107', '5108', '5109', '5110', '5113', '5080')
```

Alguém tem ideia do que pode estar acontecendo para o filtro NOT IN não funcionar? A minha consulta traz as lojas que eu filtrei fora.

Comment: ``(B.Cod Loja*1) ``  ??!!

Comment: Verifique se o conteúdo da coluna [Cod Loja] está correto, sem espaços à esquerda e/ou à direita.

Comment: O campo `[COD LOJA]` pode conter `NULL`? Se puder existir um NULL este `NOT IN` não irá apresentar o resultado esperado.

Comment: @JoséDiz eu também não entendo o por quê de (B.Cod Loja*1) . É um código legado, pediram para não alterar.

Comment: @JoséDiz eu verifiquei e não tem espaços a direita, nem a esquerda.

Comment: @anonimo não tem NULL nessse campo

Comment: O código de loja deve ter sempre 4 caracteres?

Comment: @JoséDiz nem sempre são 4 caracteres, pode ser 3 também

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao multiplicar `B.[Cod Loja]` por 1, o valor de `B.[Cod Loja]` é convertido automaticamente de valor texto para valor numérico. Isto força com que `A.[Cod Loja]` também seja transformado em valor numérico para efetuar a junção definida na cláusula ON. É a mesma coisa que

```
ON cast (A.[Cod Loja] as int) = cast (B.[Cod Loja] as int)
```

Os detalhes estão no artigo [Os perigos da conversão automática de tipos de dados](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/10/25/os-perigos-da-conversao-implicita-1/).

Sobre `(B.[Cod Loja]*1)` você comentou que "*É um código legado, pediram para não alterar*". Neste caso, já que a cláusula ON está forçando a conversão de `A.[Cod Loja]` para valor numérico, então a sugestão é que na cláusula WHERE você faça conversão manual de `A.[COD LOJA]` para valor numérico e compare então com valores numéricos. Algo assim:

```
-- código #1
SELECT A.CPF
     , A.[Cod Loja]
     , B.NomeLoja
     , A.Data_Cadastro
--INTO Cadastro
  FROM Tabela_Geral A
       LEFT JOIN Tabela_Lojas B
          ON A.[Cod Loja] = (B.[Cod Loja]*1)  
             AND B.NomeLoja <> ''
  WHERE A.Data_Cadastro <= @FIM_MES
        AND cast (A.[COD LOJA] as int) NOT IN (5100, 5106, 5107, 5108, 5109, 5110, 5113, 5080);
```

---

Como a coluna com o código de loja pode ter 3 ou 4 caracteres, eis código SQL para você verificar a qualidade dos dados da coluna `[Cod Loja]` de `Tabela_Geral`:

```
-- código #2 v3
SELECT CPF, [Cod Loja], len ([Cod Loja]) as Tamanho, Data_Cadastro
  from Tabela_Geral
  where (len([Cod Loja]) < 3) or (len([Cod Loja]) > 4);
```

e

```
-- código #3
SELECT len ([Cod Loja]), count(*) as Qtd
  from Tabela_Geral
  group by len ([Cod Loja]);
```

Comment: @Alineat Obteve o que queria com o código #1?

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda.